# Framework required for a dynamic IVRS application generator

Tags: drag-and-drop, ivr

Can anyone tell me what framework one should use for designing an IVRS generator app that would dynamically generate IVRS using drag and drop method? I have to build this app compatible to Microsoft-XP machine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the open source project called [VoiceModel](https://voicemodel.codeplex.com/).  It uses ASP.NET MVC and C# to generate [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/). VoiceXML is a web-based standard that most modern IVR's use as there programming language to define the voice/speech application. VoiceModel also supports Voxeo's cloud based IVR called [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp). There are numerous examples in this project including a couple that show how you would use a database to store the meta-data to dynamically create the voice application.  This would handle the portion of your application for generating the dynamic VoiceXML during runtime.

Without knowing much about the requirements behind the development environment you are creating I would suggest looking at HTML 5 for the portion for graphical design of the application.  This would allow users to develop and deploy in a SaaS that would work on any OS, including Microsoft XP, which Microsoft will stop supporting soon. If you are going to take all of the effort to build one of these development environments from scratch you should not lock it into one type of environment.

Having worked on teams that have built these types of tools in the past I will let you know that it is no small undertaking. Many of the large phone companies went with a buy decision before building their own because of the large investment.  And I have seen many companies fail at trying to develop a tool of their own.  Having used these types of development environments myself I can tell you that they never meet the expectation that the business owners can build the applications themselves. There is too much to know about voice user interface design (VUI), grammar development, and other skills that you cannot expect the business owners to pickup and understand.  And if I have to develop the application I am more productive using something like VoiceModel instead of the graphical environments.

But if you have to have a graphical development environment I would look at purchasing something like [Voxeo's CXP (formerly VoiceObjects)](http://developers.voiceobjects.com/) instead of building your own.  Or look at something like the [Eclipse Voice Tools Project](http://www.eclipse.org/vtp/) which is available for free. It is not as powerfull as CXP but it may meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a drag-and-drop tool that can be used on a Windows XP machine I can recommend looking at the QuickFuse platform (http://quickfuseapps.com).  QuickFuse is a browser based drag-and-drop IVR building tool that is used to design cloud-based IVR systems hosted by Plum Voice.  It supports modern versions of Firefox and Chrome that are compatible with Windows XP.